# Background fits to screen, forms don't

Tags: html, css

been a while since I posted here!

On my website I have recently got a new login screen, the screen is just one picture with no code and I have put transparent forms on them. I had to specify the locations of the forms to match the image. However, I completely forgot that the image fits to screen so while it looks good from my full screen, if I resize it, the forms are not in line with where I want them to be. You can see on my site - www.velrania.com.

So is there a way to keep the forms on the specific places where they should be while keeping the "fit to screen"? I'm familiar with CSS and html but will look into any other language to get this done.

Here's the code of the index page in case you need it:

```
<style>
body {
background-image:  url(images/home.jpg);      
}

.username{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:265px;
height:27px;
border-color: transparent;
background-color: transparent; 
position: absolute;
left: 906px;
top: 325px;
}

.password{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:265px;
height:27px;
border-color: transparent;
background-color: transparent; 
position: absolute;
left: 906px;
top: 395px;
}

.register{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:420px;
height:40px;
background-color: transparent; 
left: 750px;
top: 585px;
cursor:pointer;
border:none;    
line-height: 100;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
}

.save
{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:200px;
height:75px;
cursor:pointer;
background-color: transparent;
border:none;    
line-height: 100;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
left: 860px;
top: 475px;
}
</style>
<body background="images/home.jpg">

<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="usermail" class="username"/><br /><br />
<input type="password" name="password" class="password"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" class="save" /><input type="hidden" name="Login" />
</form>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="register"/>

</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
body {
  background-image:  url(images/home.jpg);
  margin: 0px;  
}
```

Comment: Nope, hasn't made a difference. Try it yourself, visit the site then change the size of your browser :3